# In Protégé, Sinhala language Unicode does not work. Need a direction for correct it

Tags: settings, owl, ontology, protege

I'm Using Protégé 5.5.0. When I was try to create ontology using Sinhala language, characters shown as array of boxes like below.

[image]

I have tried different solution that are mention in the web and Protégé GitHub page, But didn't work. Need help for solve this issue.

Comment: Can you share an example ontology? I'd like to check if the OWLAPI library underneath Protégé can deal with it.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable time. I have found solution for this. It's because of Java VM. My Java Runtime only support for the English. Then I have configured that for Sinhala. Now its working.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution for this. The issue was with JavaVM font rendering. It does not support for Sinhala language. Therefore, I have changed properties of JavaVM.
[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rm2ryATvMslJwXa11Eo6LHTDn30b6_vl/view?usp=sharing) find protégé-5.5.0 windows version that has rebuilt with Sinhala support.